# How to detect Java and its version in AJAX app

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, detect

I am working on web app with jquery, jqueryui, ajaxify and many jquery extensions.
At some point in the application I have to use Java applet.
The applet is run via ajax call, let's say jquery.load loads a page that generates applet code. I would like then to detect if Java is installed on the computer running the app, and if it is version 1.7+. The detection should occur only if applet is going to be used, since this functionality is to be used by limited number of users and only in certain circumstances.

I can't use deploy.js, as this script was not designed to be run via ajax call and simply fails. 
I would like to detect java only when it it really needed, i.e. when user is going to launch the applet.

How can I do that?

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: How about `navigator.javaEnabled()` for detecting if Java installed and `document.applets[0].Version` to get the version? There is no need in jQuery, just pure JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but navigator.javaEnabled()  is not working properly with IE, alt least mine, version 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to detect if java is installed.
At first I tried with navigator.javaEnabled(), but it didn't work properly with IE.
Then I tried Java deployment toolkit, but didn't succeed due to window.write which was not compatible with pages fetched via ajax. 
Then I tried to customize Java deployment toolkit following odiszapc advice ... but by the end of the day I used unmodified Java development toolkit, simply I used its versionCheck method.

If java is not detected, the user is told to download and install JRE, and link is provided.
If correct version of Java is installed then the subpage is reloaded via ajax with parameter javaOK=1. In such a case there is no java detection, just pure applet tags, in short:

```
    $SuccessUrl = FileName . "?javaOK=1&" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];   
    (...)
    $java_detect=EOQ (heredoc shoud be here, some tags don't work)
        
        var version = '1.7'; //required version

        var check = deployJava.versionCheck(version+"+"); //1.7 and higher
        if(!check){ 
          $("#sign_dialog").html("$java_err"); //wrong java or no java at all
        }else{
          $("#sign_dialog").load("$SuccessUrl");
        }
      
    EOQ;
    (...)
        if(isset($_GET['javaOK']) && $_GET['javaOK']=='1'){
          echo $applet;
        }else{
          echo $java_detect;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Java Deployment Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) in any case. When I need to some specific checks I open the java_deploy.js and see how this works. It not so hard to understand, really. For example, in Chrome it just inserts a specific  tag with certaing **uid**. Nothing complicated. Then I just exec the code doing this manually.

At the end of deploy.js it just launch Java check after the page load. One method call. I've just removed this code and launch it manually in my own code.

Comment: Deployment toolkit uses deploy.js, and as stated in the question it doesn't work. Deployment technique from toolkit uses window.write or which contradicts with pages fetched via ajax. That's way it cannot be used in ajax fetched page with applet code.

Comment: Yes, it uses document.write that reloads page. I've juse removed this code with $(document.body).append() and all works fine. Yes, it needs to rewrite deploy.js.

Comment: I am just trying to find functions responsible for detection here - http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt, looked into that earlier,  but for some reason I can't see that functionality. I don't want any auto install functionality, pure detection. If JRE <1.7 I will instruct user to install latest JRE or contact system administrator.